# How can I fix EInvalidOperation related to ImageList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, timagelist

My application (write on Delphi 7)runs correctly on Windows XP SP3 but when I try to run it on Windows 7 this exception occurs:

**EInvalidOperation with message "Invalid ImageList"**

This is the main application code:

```
  Application.Initialize;

  tmpSplash.GoNextMsg;
  Application.CreateForm(TdmImages, dmImages);

  tmpSplash.GoNextMsg; // Collegamento database
  Application.CreateForm(TdmCharter, dmCharter);


  tmpSplash.GoNextMsg; // Caricamento immagini
  Application.CreateForm(TfrMain, frMain);

  tmpSplash.GoNextMsg; // init: Anagrafica
  frameAnagrafica := TframeAnagrafica.Create(Application);

  tmpSplash.GoNextMsg; // init: Flotta
  frameFlotta := TframeFlotta.Create(Application);
  //Application.CreateForm(TframeFlotta, frameFlotta);

  ...
  ...
```

The module dmImages has been created correctly, such as the frMain, but when
will created the object frameAnagrafica then raise the exception on the constructor method:

```
type
    TframeAnagrafica = class(TMyCustomFrame)
...
...

{$R *.dfm}
constructor TframeAnagrafica.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner); 

end;
```

And the "super-class" of TframeAnagrafica:

```
TMyCustomFrame = class(TFrame)
...
...

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyCustomFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner); <-- Exception here

end;
```

In windows XP no problem, but using Windows 7 occurs the problem.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could show some of your code. Otherwise, our hopes of helping are dashed.

Comment: What version of Delphi? What types of images are in the image list? How are they being loaded into the image list? You need to be specific and provide details if you want us to help you. We can't see your code, read your mind, or access your machine to debug it for you from here, so all we can do is use what information you provide us with to help. Please [edit] your question and provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking us?

Comment: Probably something wrong with the application manifest.

Comment: Please read [StackOverflow question checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Comment: I note that you edited the question. It's good that you are doing so, but you won't get any help until you provide some real information. Problem solving does not happen by magic. Information and evidence is gathered. And then solutions can be formulated. You'll need to do an awful lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception like this can occur if you use a value for the property `ColorDepth` that is not supported by the current operating system. Or it can occur if you try to use a 32Bit imagelist with alpha channel (`TColorDepth.cd32Bit`) but do not have an XP manifest in you application. To do so, include the unit `xpman` in your project or choose "Enable runtime themes" at "Project > Options > Application > Appearance > Runtime themes" ind Delphi XE2 or higher.

Comment: I've tried to remove the control XPManifest on the main form and the application run correclty.

Comment: Better than removing the XP manifest would be to get the imagelist compatible with XP and later. Not having an XP manifest will cause certain libraries to load in a Windows 2000 version and themeing will be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I just received updates from windows 10 and it messed up my machine it took away permissions to my folders.  I am currently running Delphi and when I was trying to print out reports I getting error message Class Elnvalidoperation can't generate report.  It was because my printer disappeared and I had to reinstall and the issue seems to be fixed.